# QtQuick, QML-based application contents invisible

Tags: qt-creator, qml, qt-quick

I have created a simple QtQuick application in QtCreator (based on QtSDK 4.7.3), which builds successfully and runs from within the QtCreator IDE without any problems.

**The problem**: When I try to run the same application manually from the file-system, it shows empty (white) background only.

- A assume that all needed library dependencies are resolved properly - without that the application wouldn't even run.
- I'm targeting Desktop and I compile in both: Windows and Ubuntu environments (QtDSK 4.7.3 on both).
- Compiler: MinGW 4.4.

Can anyone please spot what the problem is?

Comment: Here's what I've found so far. On Ubuntu the application doesn't start if I use Krusader fila manager. When I use Nautilus - Qml contents are shown properly. Now the question is why does it behave differently on Linux, and how to solve it on Windows?

Comment: Check the location of your qml files, they should be accessible to the binary executable.

Comment: Indeed - this seems to be the solution. QtCreator on Ubuntu automatically copied qml files, while on Windows they were located one level up in the directory structure. Thank you! If you post your comment as an answer, I should be able to accept it so that you get points. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the location of your qml files, they should be accessible to the binary executable.